# EF Code First foreign key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EF Code First to map to an existing DB2 database. This is a one-to-many relationship, and unfortunately I cannot easily create views or change the schema.

The schema for the parent table has the following keys:

```
 Type (char(1))
 ServiceDate (datetime)
 FormNumber (varchar(8))
```

The child table (Details) has the following keys

```
 ServiceDate (datetime) (also a foreign key to ServiceDate on the parent table)
 FormNumber (varchar(8)) (also a foreign key to ServiceDate on the parent table)
 SpecificServiceDate (datetime)
 LineNumber (varchar(8))
```

I'd like to use fluent mapping to create the relationship. If I do:

```
 .HasMany(e => e.Details).HasForeignKey(e => new {e.ServiceDate, e.FormNumber});
```

...I get an error saying the key does not match the primary key. Ideas on how to set this up? Thanks.

**Edit**

OK, EF doesn't natively support this. Is there a workaround to lazy-load the data?

This is for read-only, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not even sure how that would work.  What happens if you have a FormNumber=1, ServiceDate=1/1/2013, Type=A and a FormNumber=1, ServiceDate=1/1/2013, Type=B?  There is no way for Details to uniquely select which record is it's parent.  I can't believe DB/2 would allow this kind of foreign key relationship when it's not uniquely identifying.

Comment: This is off of an old AS400 system, the primary table is actually a UNION view, and the foreign keys are more convention than anything else. Not fun. :-(

Comment: EF does not support views very well either.  In particular, EF will treat any field that is non-nullable as part of a composite primary key.  You probably will not be able to create a relationship here.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Relation in EF has same rules as in database. If your parent table has three columns in primary key your dependent table must have same three columns in foreign key.

I'm not sure if you can define such relation in DB2 without marking `ServiceDate` and `FormNumber` as unique key (in such case there would be no reason to have `Type` in PK as well) but you definitely can't define it in SQL server which is blue print for EF. Anyway EF currently doesn't support unique keys to form relation.